# Can not pull any image in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, hyperkit

Im on macOS and im using `minikube` with `hyperkit` driver: `minikube start --driver=hyperkit`

and everything seems ok...

with `minikube status`:

```
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

with `minikube version`:

```
minikube version: v1.24.0
```

with `kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:35:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and with `kubectl get no`:

```
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   13m   v1.22.3
```

my problem is when i deploy anything, it wont pull any image...

for instance:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
```

then `kubectl get pods`:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-nfc64   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          13m
```

then i tried to figure out what is the problem?

```
k describe pod/hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-nfc64
```

here is the result:

```
Name:         hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-nfc64
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.64.8
Start Time:   Sun, 16 Jan 2022 10:49:27 +0330
Labels:       app=hello-minikube
              pod-template-hash=6ddfcc9757
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           172.17.0.5
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.5
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757
Containers:
  echoserver:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
    Image ID:       
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-k5qql (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-k5qql:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  18m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-nfc64 to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    16m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet            Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4"
  Warning  Failed     16m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed     16m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     15m (x6 over 18m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    3m34s (x59 over 18m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4"
```

then tried to get some logs!:

`k logs pod/hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-nfc64` and `k logs deploy/hello-minikube`

both returns the same result:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "echoserver" in pod "hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-nfc64" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

this deployment was an example from [minikube documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

but i have no idea why it doesnt pull any image...

Comment: I found [here](https://acloud.guru/forums/Kubernetes-Security/discussion/-MF9J-EhtyweTCpqPL_m/Hello-Node%20Error:%20ImagePullBackOff%20Status) similar error. Is the solution provided there helpful?

Comment: Hello @kkopczak, i wasn't here for quite a long time, sorry about that. Unfortunately the answer in that article wasn't solved my problem, because still i cant pull any image... but thanks anyway for your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly same problem.
I found out that my internet connection was slow,
the timout to pull an image is `120` seconds, so  kubectl **could not** pull the  image in under `120` seconds.

first use minikube to pull the image you need
for example:

```
minikube image load k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
```

and then everything will work because now kubectl will use the image that is stored locally.

Comment: First pull the image: `docker image pull k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.tutorialworks.com/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff/):

> The status  `ImagePullBackOff`  means that a Pod couldn’t start, because Kubernetes couldn’t pull a container image. The ‘BackOff’ part means that Kubernetes will keep trying to pull the image, with an increasing delay (‘back-off’).

[Here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/) is also a handbook about pushing images into a minikube cluster.

[This handbook](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/#:%7E:text=Client.,Timeout%20exceeded%20while%20awaiting%20headers&text=This%20error%20indicates%20that%20the%20container%20runtime%20running%20within%20the,to%20%2D%2Ddocker%2Denv%20HTTPS_PROXY%20.) describes your issue:

> Unable to pull images..Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

```
Unable to pull images, which may be OK:

failed to pull image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.3": output: Error response from daemon:
Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
(Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

> This error indicates that the container runtime running within the VM does not have access to the internet.

See [possible workarounds](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/#:%7E:text=Client.,Timeout%20exceeded%20while%20awaiting%20headers&text=This%20error%20indicates%20that%20the%20container%20runtime%20running%20within%20the,to%20%2D%2Ddocker%2Denv%20HTTPS_PROXY%20.).

Comment: Hello @wytrzymaływiktor Unfortunately no, i still can't pull any image... i actually know that i cant pull any image probably because my pod doesn't have any access to the internet but i don't know why? and how can i fix it? i test docker-desktop and it was ok, also i tried minikube with and with-out VPN but my problem still remained... (Also i tried to remove and re-install the minikube many times, but still nothing changed...)

Comment: Did you try possible workarounds I linked?

Answer (score -2):

I encountered some similar issue, it is fixed by using echoserver:1.10 instead of echoserver:1.4

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31587543)